# How to delete a RasterImage in autocad using .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, image, raster, autocad

I have a raster image jpg attached as Xref in the dwg and I want to dettach the file. How can I delete it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything special about it being an Xref necessarily. I took the code below from an article titled, "[Detaching an AutoCAD external reference using .NET](http://Detaching%20an%20AutoCAD%20external%20reference%20using%20.NET)".

From the **description**:

> There’s nothing very surprising about the code, although it does show
>   how to loop selection based on a core property of the selected object
>   (or even one connected to it, as is the case, here), rather than just
>   trusting AutoCAD to do so based on the object’s type. We also have to
>   pass the ObjectId of the defining BlockTableRecord to the
>   Database.DetachXref() method, which is certainly worth being aware of.

**Code:**

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;

namespace XrefApplication
{
  public class Commands
  {
    [CommandMethod("DX")]
    static public void DetachXref()
    {
      Document doc =
        Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
      Database db = doc.Database;
      Editor ed = doc.Editor;

      // Select an external reference

      Transaction tr =
        db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
      using (tr)
      {
        BlockTableRecord btr = null;
        ObjectId xrefId = ObjectId.Null;

        // We'll loop, as we need to open the block and
        // underlying definition to check the block is
        // an external reference during selection

        do
        {
          PromptEntityOptions peo =
            new PromptEntityOptions(
              "\nSelect an external reference:"
            );
          peo.SetRejectMessage("\nMust be a block reference.");
          peo.AddAllowedClass(typeof(BlockReference), true);

          PromptEntityResult per = ed.GetEntity(peo);
          if (per.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
            return;

          // Open the block reference

          BlockReference br =
            (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(
              per.ObjectId,
              OpenMode.ForRead
            );

          // And the underlying block table record

          btr =
            (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(
              br.BlockTableRecord,
              OpenMode.ForRead
            );

          // If it's an xref, store its ObjectId

          if (btr.IsFromExternalReference)
          {
            xrefId = br.BlockTableRecord;
          }
          else
          {
            // Otherwise print a message and loop

            ed.WriteMessage(
              "\nMust be an external reference."
            );
          }
        }
        while (!btr.IsFromExternalReference);

        // If we have a valid ObjectID for the xref, detach it

        if (xrefId != ObjectId.Null)
        {
          db.DetachXref(xrefId);
          ed.WriteMessage("\nExternal reference detached.");
        }

        // We commit the transaction simply for performance
        // reasons, as the detach is independent

        tr.Commit();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From [MyCadSite.com](http://www.mycadsite.com/tutorials/level_4/4-7.htm) you can read more about Xrefs outside of the C# API. In the interface, it all appears to attach the same way. When looking at [this code on Typepad](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/06/finding-all-xrefs-in-the-current-database-using-cnet.html), you can see that the references are all treated the same way in the database as well.

**From the author:**

> The db.GetHostDwgXrefGraph() method returns the Xref hierarchy for the
>   current drawing as an XrefGraph object. Here’s a simple code snippet
>   to demonstrate its use – in this case to print the Xref structure of
>   the current drawing to the command line.

**Code:**

```
[CommandMethod("XrefGraph")]
public static void XrefGraph()
{
  Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
  Database db = doc.Database;
  Editor ed = doc.Editor;
  using (Transaction Tx = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
    ed.WriteMessage("\n---Resolving the XRefs------------------");
    db.ResolveXrefs(true, false);
    XrefGraph xg = db.GetHostDwgXrefGraph(true);
    ed.WriteMessage("\n---XRef's Graph-------------------------");
    ed.WriteMessage("\nCURRENT DRAWING");
    GraphNode root = xg.RootNode;
    printChildren(root, "|-------", ed, Tx);
    ed.WriteMessage("\n----------------------------------------\n");
  }
}

// Recursively prints out information about the XRef's hierarchy
private static void printChildren(GraphNode i_root, string i_indent,
                                  Editor i_ed, Transaction i_Tx)
{
  for (int o = 0; o < i_root.NumOut; o++)
  {
    XrefGraphNode child = i_root.Out(o) as XrefGraphNode;
    if (child.XrefStatus == XrefStatus.Resolved)
    {
      BlockTableRecord bl =
        i_Tx.GetObject(child.BlockTableRecordId, OpenMode.ForRead)
            as BlockTableRecord;
      i_ed.WriteMessage("\n" + i_indent + child.Database.Filename);
      // Name of the Xref (found name)
      // You can find the original path too:
      //if (bl.IsFromExternalReference == true)
      // i_ed.WriteMessage("\n" + i_indent + "Xref path name: "
      //                      + bl.PathName);
      printChildren(child, "| " + i_indent, i_ed, i_Tx);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The db.GetHostDwgXrefGraph() method returns only Xref hiearchy for dwg but for the raster image and underlay types, you need to search for them in the DBDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution for the problem:

```
 private void DetachRasterImage(Transaction transaction, Database database, List<string> jpgPaths)
    {
        Dictionary<ObjectId, RasterImageDef> imageDefinitions = new Dictionary<ObjectId, RasterImageDef>();
        DBDictionary imageDictionary = (DBDictionary)transaction.GetObject(RasterImageDef.GetImageDictionary(database), OpenMode.ForWrite);
        foreach (DBDictionaryEntry entry in imageDictionary)
        {
            ObjectId id = (ObjectId)entry.Value;
            RasterImageDef rasterImageDef = transaction.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite) as RasterImageDef;
            if (jpgPaths.Contains(rasterImageDef.LocateActivePath()))
                imageDefinitions.Add(id, rasterImageDef);
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<ObjectId, RasterImageDef> item in imageDefinitions)
        {
            imageDictionary.Remove(item.Key);
            item.Value.Erase();
        }           
    }
```